# Two sample t-test vs One-sample t-test on residuals

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

For some arbitrary data, I have the raw data and a fitted model (not a regression model, but more so a model that accounts for noise and imperfections the data acquisition). I want to see how closely the model resembles my data. I can use a two sample dependent t test, comparing the raw data to the fitted regression model, testing to see if their means significantly differ. Or I can take the different of the raw data and fitted model (which is the residual) and preform a one sample t test on the residual, testing to see if the mean of the residual plot significantly differs from 0. What is the difference between these two approaches? Is one invalid. I also want to extrapolate this idea to the Wilcoxon signed ranked test for one sample (on the residual) or two sample (between the model and the raw data).

Comment: Could you explain what is the relationship between "raw data" and "fitted regression model"?  Is the fit based on those data or on other data?  What specifically is the regression model (because that determines the appropriate way to test the fit)?

Comment: Welcome, Bodhi! when you fit a regression model to data with some statistical software, you would also get information about how close the fit is to the data. Did you make use of this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I guess I should clarify that the model is not actually a regression model. The raw data is very noisy and inaccurate, but there exists reputable software that does some transformations to the data, and also fits the data to resemble what “perfect data” should look like. The program that does this fit returns how noisy the data was, and also has its own measurement of how the raw data fits the model it produced, however this measurement is not great. Therefore, often the best thing to look at is the residual plot.

Comment: Hi Bodhi, the information in your comment, that you did not use a regression model, is very important to understand your question. Could you please edit your question accordingly? @RachelAltman's short answer assumes that you used a regression model and that you want use the average of the residuals as criterion. This is a poor criterion in general, and in regression, it is lousy criterion, because the average is zero, by design. Always.

Comment: ohhh, makes sense. I will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell us specifically what you mean by a "fitted model"?  And, again, we need to know how that fitted model might be related to your data: is it based on those data or is it fitted from an independent set of data?  And how specifically is it fitted?

Comment: When you have paired data, in general you would use a paired test because it is more powerful. In your case, when there is considerable variation in the raw data, it is *much* more powerful - try it out :-). Otherwise, I'd agree with @PeterFlom, a test does not tell you much here. It can only show if the fitted model seems to deviate systematically from the raw data, *on average*. The model can be totally off, and still the mean of residuals is zero or close to it. In regression analysis, one always inspects graphs instead of a formal test.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks. I honestly I’m not sure exactly how the software fits the data, but I know that it using external and independent information than just the raw data. I’m also preforming autocorrelation tests for independence on the residuals.

Comment: What was the result of the autocorrelation tests? And did you also perform a test to see if the residuals are approximately normal distributed? Is it possible to fit the same model to the data, just by ordinary normal (multivariate) regression? In that case, maybe you can compare the two model fits.

Comment: I haven't yet preformed the autocorrelation test, but on each of the 7000+ different residual graphs, all have distributions almost exactly around 0. So I think I agree with some other posts that the model might be intentionally fitted such that the mean of the residuals is 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OLS estimation, by construction, the average of the residuals will be 0 AND the average response will equal the average fitted value. So neither of these tests is meaningful.

Comment: I haven't any idea what the question is asking, because I can think of several plausible interpretations that fit its words.  Could you tell us what your interpretation of it is?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use any kind of test. I would graph the fitted values (predictions) against the actual values in various ways. Boxplots, Tukey mean difference plots (aka Bland Altman plots), maybe do some things that involve some of the independent variables (a trellis plot might be good).  And so on.

If you insist on a test, then some sort of test of equivalence seems much better than a test of difference.